# Iterate over files and convert with a new name / directory

Tags: beginner, bash, sed

I'm pretty new to bash scripting.  I want a script that I can run in a directory that contains `.md` files, runs pandoc on them, and delivers the output to a sibling folder `html`, i.e. my folder structure is like this:

```
.
├── html
└── md
```

Here is what I have working, I just don't know if I'm following good practices or if there's a nicer / more readable way of doing what I'm doing.

```
#! /bin/bash
# run this from a folder containing markdown files
# it delivers html to the sibling html folder
if hash pandoc 2>/dev/null; then
  for file in ./*.md ; do
    echo Converting $file
    cat "$file" | pandoc -o "$(echo $file | sed 's/^./..\/html/' |  sed 's/.md$/.html/')"
  done
else
  echo "I need pandoc installed"
fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **[UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)**. `pandoc` takes the input file name as an argument. `echo $file | pandoc -o outfile` is equivalent to `pandoc -o outfile $file`. One process invocation down.
- **UUOS** (`sed` in this case). `bash` has very rich string transformation features built in. For example, `${file%md}` (see **`Parameter expansion`** section of `man bash`) will strip the `md` suffix form the filename. So consider

  ```
  for file in *.md; do
      pandoc -o ../html/${file%md}html
  done
  ```

  Two more process invocations down.
- If by any chance an `.md` filename contains funny characters (like whitespace), the substitution will produce unexpected results. It is safer to use double quotes, as in `"${....}".

PS: It might be beneficial to abandon the shell script altogether in favor of `make`, with a `Makefile` having a single stem rule

```
../html/%.html: %.md
    pandoc -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Awesome thank you!  My workplace actually has an *award* for UUOC, I think I'll need to apply for it :)

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  My script has evolved a bit since I asked the original question.  Interested to know if there's a nicer way to pass an optional parameter to pandoc.

Comment: If you've got a new version of the code it is time for a new code review.  It is ok to open a new question on here with modified code.  It is nice to link to the previous question too.